# Using mean value theorem for multiple inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove that $\frac{(x-1)}{x} < \ln x < x-1$ for $x > 1$.

I was thinking of breaking up the inequality into \frac{(x-1)}{x} < \ln x$, and $\ln x < x-1$ and just proving each individual inequality using the mean value theorem approach:

So, $\ln x - \frac{x-1}{x} > 0$.  So, $\frac{x\ln x - x - 1}{x} > 0$, so let $g(x) = x\ln x - x - 1 > 0$.
Thus, $g'(x)$

Answer (score 3):

The Mean Value Theorem states that there exist $c\in(a,b)$ such, that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.
For $f(x)=\ln x, a=1,b=x$ we get $\frac{1}{\xi} =\frac{\ln x - \ln 1}{x-1}$ for some $\xi$ in $(1,x)$.
$1<\xi<x \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{\xi}<1$, which gives $\frac{1}{x}<\frac{\ln x}{x-1}<1$, then multiply by $x-1>0$.